# Undefined method `to_ary' when rendering an Enumerator over Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

When rendering large CSV documents, we are rendering an `Enumerator` which allows the browser to stream the document as its created. The `Enumerator` is passed to a controller render_csv method:

```
  def render_csv(body:, filename:)
    # Tell Rack to stream the content
    headers.delete("Content-Length")
    # Don't buffer when going through proxy servers
    headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"

    headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
    headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.now.httpdate
    headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present"

    headers["Content-Disposition"] = %(attachment; filename="#{filename}.csv")
    self.response_body = body
  end
```

This used to work until Puma 6 which now raises `` undefined method `to_ary' `` on the enumerator being passed:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `to_ary' for #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000000011e938568>:each>>
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace so we can see where the error is actually occuring?

Comment: @engineersmnky I wasn't able to get a full stack trace. I just had the puma.log. I ended up fixing with the send_stream method.

Comment: Thanks for raising this question. Any chance you could share your `Gemfile.lock` here too? We're facing the same issue and doing `include ActionController::Live` (as required for the `send_stream` workaround) causes timeouts on various - unrelated - pages. Interested to see if a specific third party gem is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started seeing this bug after upgrading to rails 7.1.1, it was fixed by upgrading to 7.1.2

Comment: Same here, upgrading Rails from 7.1.1 to 7.1.2 fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We were able to fix the issue by using the [ActionController::Live#send_stream method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html#method-i-send_stream). Previously, we just set the body equal to the enumerator object.

The resulting code:

```
  def render_csv(body:, filename:)
    headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"
    headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
    headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.now.httpdate
    send_stream(filename: "#{filename}.csv") do |stream|
      body.each {|line| stream.write line }
    end
  end
```